Trouble finding solution for error "Cannot resolve Class" in XML and Kotlin
I am kind of new to Android app developement and I am trying to Programm this app, which basically replaces the counting system in a card game. The Problem is, that when I try to create a layout with XML, I get the error "Cannot Resolve Class". This error is not an error message in the compiler window, but if you hover over the Text of a certain Tag, you see it. If I try to acces this view, the app crashes. I do not get any error messages shown on my devices or anything. Can anyone help me?
My XML code looks like this right now:
// This AddUser-Tag in the following line is the point where i see the error message
<AddUser xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm a button" />



</AddUser>

My Kotlin Code is the following:
package com.example.schaetzen

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.schaetzen.ui.theme.SchaetzenTheme

class ATTYN {

    companion object {
        // Erstellen der Objektklasse für Spieler + Punkte
        data class Player(val name:String, var Points: List<Int>)

        // Erstellen der Variable, die die Liste aller Spieler darstellt
        var AllPlayers = arrayOf<Player>()
    }

}




class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    val create = onCreate()


    fun onCreate() {

        setContentView(R.layout.adduser)

    }

}

class AddUser{

}


I tried to create a class in my MainActivity.kt File, which didnt help and the error still exists. I also tried searching on google, but i only found different Cases than mine.

Wait! AddUser is not a View. It can't be treated as a View because it doesn't inherit a view.

I'm assuming that the xml is a layout?  You need for AddUser to be a legal View (it needs to derive from View, which it doesn't in your code) and you need to use the fully qualified class name com.example.schaetzen.AddUser.  And if you want other views inside of it it needs to be a ViewGroup, not just a View.
Although there's a good chance you shouldn't be doing any of this-  why are you making your top level view a custom view type?  There are reasons to do things like that, but it's very unusual.  Chances are you're just misunderstanding how to write a UI and doing things you don't actually want to do.
